# An urn contains $4$ blue and $4$ red marbles. What is $P(A\vert B)$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

An urn contains  $4$ blue and $4$ red marbles. At first a marble is drawn (without looking) and removed from the urn. Then, a marble is drawn from the urn, its color recorded and put back in the urn. This process is repeated $1000$ times. Let $A$ be the event that the removed marble is blue. Let $B$ the event exactly $503$ draws out of $1000$ draws are red. What is $P(A\vert B)$?

**My attempt:**

$$P(A\vert B)=\frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(B)}$$

If red removed: $\implies 3 \, \text{red},4 \, \text{blue} \implies P(\text{red})=\frac{3}{7}$

If blue removed: $\implies 4 \, \text{red},3 \, \text{blue} \implies P(\text{red})=\frac{4}{7}$

Probability of choosing exactly $503$ out of $1000$ is: $${1000 \choose 503}p^{503}(1-p)^{497}$$

Therefore: $$P(B)=\frac{1}{2}{1000 \choose 503}\left( \frac{3}{7}\right)^{503}\left( \frac{4}{7}\right)^{497}+\frac{1}{2}{1000 \choose 503}\left( \frac{4}{7}\right)^{503}\left( \frac{3}{7}\right)^{497}=1.15 \cdot10^{-6}$$

$$P(A\cap B)= \frac{1}{2}{1000 \choose 503}\left( \frac{4}{7}\right)^{503}\left( \frac{3}{7}\right)^{497}=9.78 \cdot 10^{-7}$$

$$P(A \vert B)=\frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(B)}=\frac{9.78 \cdot10^{-7}}{1.15 \cdot 10^{-6}}=0.8504 \approx 85 \%$$

Is my reasoning correct or did I make some mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is spot on, except for the minor mistake of incorrectly adding a leading factor of $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ to the computation of $p(A\cap B).$

An intuitive visualization that you made a mistake is by noticing that

$$p(B) = p(A\cap B) + p([\neg A] \cap B).$$

Therefore,

$$p(A|B) = \frac{p(A\cap B)}{p(A\cap B) + p([\neg A] \cap B)}.$$

**Edit**
Also, just noticed, you have a typo in your very last equation, where you switched the numerator and denominator.  In effect, the typo proved harmless, because your common sense kicked in, to force you to construe the larger number as the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I fixed the factor and edited the result. Is an intuitive interpretation that "knowing" I got more red draws than blue draws in my $1000$ draws, it is much more likely that i removed a blue ball at the beginning than a red ball?

Comment: @qmd Yes, exactly.  In fact, I personally regard intuition as more important in the study of Probability/Combinatorics than in (some) other branches of Math.  It is true that you are constantly having to stretch your intuition, re any branch of Math, because any branch of Math is (in effect) a foreign language.  However, I regard the stress on the intuition for a new student as *greater*, with respect to Probability/Combinatorics.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question that I am working on right now that relates to this question. Let the event $D$ be the event that between $450$ and $550$ blue marbles are drawn in 1000 draws and the event $E$ be the event that between $379$ and $479$ blue marbles are drawn. Which event is more likely? Intuitively i would say $D$ because it seems like it is a range around the average amount of blue marbles I would expect and therefore more likely. However, I can't think of a clever way to show this?

Comment: @qmd Two reactions: [1] I am ignorant of [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics), which is what your 2nd question seems to be focusing on, rather than Probability. [2] Doesn't matter here, because I don't know the answer anyway.  However, normally, with a 2nd **major** question, protocol says - make the question into a separate mathSE posting.

Comment: Ok will do! Thank you very much for your help though. I really need to start thinking more "intuitively" like you said. It would have raised some red flags right away when I got $\approx 40 \%$ as an answer earlier.