# Is it more likely to get $450-550$ or $379-479$ blue marbles in $1000$ draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

This is a follow up question to this: [An urn contains $4$ blue and $4$ red marbles. What is $P(A\vert B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175007/an-urn-contains-4-blue-and-4-red-marbles-what-is-pa-vert-b/4175035?noredirect=1#comment8650254_4175035)

An urn contains  $4$ blue and $4$ red marbles. At first a marble is drawn (without looking) and removed from the urn. Then, a marble is drawn from the urn, its color recorded and put back in the urn. This process is repeated $1000$ times. Let $D$ be the event that between $450$ and $550$ blue marbles are drawn and let $E$ be the event that between $379$ and $479$ blue marbles are drawn. Which event is more likely?

Intuitively I would say that event $D$ is more likely. This is because on average I would expect around $500$ blue marbles drawn. Since the event $D$ is centered around this average it seems more likely to me than event $E$ that is centered around a value of $429$. Is there a nice way to show this mathematically by maybe using some sort of approximation?

Comment: Apply the central limit theorem, and it should be easy to show.

Comment: @DonThousand Ok I will try that. Is it the case that I can consider this as a sum of bernoulli random variables? If yes my mean would be $np=500$ and my variance $np(1-p)=500\cdot \frac{1}{4}=125$. But this is ignoring that one of the marbles was removed at the beginning and the probabilities are skewed. Do I need to somehow include this fact?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can ignore it since there's a symmetry between the cases when a blue marble and a red marble is removed.

Comment: @DonThousand That makes sense! I will try it using the CLT. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation is actually quite straightforward, but there is a fundamental flaw in your intuition that I feel is more important to address, because it illustrates a principle that one needs to understand thoroughly if one is to not be led astray.

> The expected value is not necessarily near a mode of a distribution.

This statement, while simple on its face, may not seem to have immediate applicability to your reasoning.  However, the relationship becomes apparent once you observe that we are dealing with two distinct conditional distributions for the number of blue marbles drawn, once the unobserved marble is removed, and neither of them have their mode near $500$.  Therefore, the probability of event $D$ occurs over a range of unconditional outcomes that will not cover a large likelihood of occurrence, because in either case of the initial marble being removed, the conditional mean (and thus the mode) is too far away.

Explicitly, we note that if $X$ is the random number of blue marbles drawn, and $B$ is the event that the initial marble removed is blue, then $$X \mid B \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 1000, p = 3/7),$$ and $$X \mid \bar B \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 1000, p = 4/7).$$  Thus the conditional means and variances are $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid B] = \frac{3000}{7} \approx 428.57, \quad \operatorname{E}[X \mid \bar B] = \frac{4000}{7} \approx 571.43, \\ \operatorname{Var}[X \mid B] = \operatorname{Var}[X \mid \bar B] = \frac{12000}{49} \approx 244.898.$$

This in turn implies that the standard deviation is about $\sigma \approx 15.64$, and thus the outcome $X = 500$ is just over $4.5$ standard deviations from the means of either conditional distribution.  Thus the unconditional distribution of the number of blue marbles drawn is strongly **bimodal**.

The exact calculation is
$$\Pr[D] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x=450}^{550} \binom{1000}{x} \left( (3/7)^x (4/7)^{1000-x} + (4/7)^x (3/7)^{1000-x} \right), \\
\Pr[E] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x=379}^{479} \binom{1000}{x} \left( (3/7)^x (4/7)^{1000-x} + (4/7)^x (3/7)^{1000-x} \right).
$$
The normal approximation to the binomial would work here to evaluate the sum;
$$\Pr[D] \approx \frac{1}{2}\left(\Pr[1.369 \le Z \le 7.759] + \Pr[-7.759 \le Z \le -1.369]\right) \approx 0.085, \\
\Pr[E] \approx \frac{1}{2}\left(\Pr[-3.168 \le Z \le 3.222] + \Pr[-12.296 \le Z \le -5.906]\right) \approx 0.499.$$

This is not continuity-corrected but you can already see the dramatic difference.  In the case of event $E$, almost all of the probability is contributed by the scenario in which the initial marble removed is blue, thus making the conditional distribution have mean $428.57$, and in this case, which occurs with probability $1/2$, the chance of getting between $379$ and $479$ blue marbles in $1000$ draws is almost assured; this is why the resulting unconditional probability is so close to $1/2$.  But in the case of event $D$, you are highly unlikely in either case of the initial removed marble to get anywhere near $450$ to $550$ blue marbles because the conditional distributions don't have their modes near $500$.

---

The reason why I furnished an outline of the calculation in this case, when very minimal effort was shown in that regard, is because I consider it to be virtually **irrelevant** to the true pedagogical value of the question, which is to illustrate how we must be careful with using intuitive arguments.

Comment: I am really sorry fo the late response. It was 2 in the morning where I live an I didn't see your answer until I got up. First of all I would like to thank you for everything you have written. My intution was so off on this one and reading through you answer really made me realize why it was off so much. I worked through all the calculations this morning and tried to follow everything. However, I am having trouble getting the same values and therefore the same conclusions from the normal approximation. (Calculation in next comment)

Comment: From the central limit theorem we have:$\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}=Z_n$. Take the case $\text{the removed ball is blue}$ and I want to approximate the event $D$ :

$$\begin{aligned}\implies \Pr\left(450 \le D \le550 \right)&= \Pr \left(\frac{450-\frac{3000}{7}}{\sqrt{1000}\sqrt{\frac{12000}{49}}} \le \frac{D-\frac{3000}{7}}{\sqrt{1000}\sqrt{\frac{12000}{49}}} \le \frac{550-\frac{3000}{7}}{\sqrt{1000}\sqrt{\frac{12000}{49}}}\right)\\[10pt]&=\Pr\left( \frac{1}{40} \le Z \le \frac{17}{20}\right)=\Pr\left(0.025 \le Z \le 0.85\right)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This is not one of the approximations that you have posted in your answer so I am guessing I am making a mistake with the normal approximation which also gives me different probabilities for the events $D$ and $E$.

Comment: @qmd No worries!  I'm glad that you found this answer useful.  As for the use of the normal approximation, we do not divide by $\sqrt{1000}$, because the sampling distribution is binomial. So if we have $Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$, then we approximate $Y$ with a normal distribution whose mean and variance match $Y$; i.e., $$Z = \frac{Y - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$$ approximately. But if you do wish to invoke CLT, then you would do so on the **Bernoulli** distributed observations whose standard deviation is $\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)} = \sqrt{12/49}$.

Comment: In other words, you are trying to apply the CLT to the binomial sampling distribution but there is only one such realization.  If you instead apply it to the Bernoulli observations that comprise the sample, then it will work because $n = 1000$; in fact, this is why the normal approximation to the binomial is justified.